# Difference between BalancedRandomForestClassifier and sklearn.ensemble.RandomForest + RandomUnderSampling

Tags: classification, random-forest, scikit-learn, unbalanced-classes

What is the difference between fitting training data with imblearn.BalancedRandomForestClassifier compared to using sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier + imblearn.under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler ?

I tried to run both methods on the same dataset but got different results.

Dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud

```py
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.ensemble as ensemble
from imblearn.ensemble import BalancedRandomForestClassifier
from imblearn.pipeline import make_pipeline as make_pipeline_imb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from imblearn import over_sampling, under_sampling
from imblearn.metrics import classification_report_imbalanced

# Credit-card kaggle
cc_df = pd.read_csv("creditcard.csv")

# X: features
x_cc = cc_df.iloc[:,1:30]
x_cc = np.array(x_cc)

# Y: labels
y_cc = cc_df['Class'].values

# Original
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    x_cc,
    y_cc,
    random_state=42)

RUS = under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy='auto',
                                        return_indices=False,
                                        random_state=42,
                                        replacement=False,
                                        ratio=None)

RF = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(
    n_estimators=100,
    criterion='gini',
    max_depth=None,
    min_samples_split=2,
    min_samples_leaf=2,
    min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
    max_features='auto',
    max_leaf_nodes=None,
    min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
    min_impurity_split=None,
    bootstrap=True,
    oob_score=False,
    n_jobs=1,
    random_state=42,
    verbose=0,
    warm_start=False,
    class_weight=None)

pl_RUS_RF = make_pipeline_imb(RUS, RF)
pl_RUS_RF.fit(x_train, y_train)

BRF = BalancedRandomForestClassifier(
    n_estimators=100,
    criterion='gini',
    max_depth=None,
    min_samples_split=2,
    min_samples_leaf=2,
    min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
    max_features='auto',
    max_leaf_nodes=None,
    min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
    bootstrap=True,
    oob_score=False,
    sampling_strategy='auto',
    replacement=False,
    n_jobs=1,
    random_state=42,
    verbose=0,
    warm_start=False,
    class_weight=None)

BRF.fit(x_train, y_train)

print(classification_report_imbalanced(y_test, BRF.predict(x_test)))
print(classification_report_imbalanced(y_test, pl_RUS_RF.predict(x_test)))
```

Results:

```
BRF

                   pre       rec       spe        f1       geo       iba       sup

          0       1.00      0.98      0.92      0.99      0.95      0.91     71089
          1       0.07      0.92      0.98      0.12      0.95      0.90       113

avg / total       1.00      0.98      0.92      0.99      0.95      0.91     71202


pl_RUS_RF
                   pre       rec       spe        f1       geo       iba       sup

          0       1.00      0.97      0.91      0.99      0.94      0.89     71089
          1       0.05      0.91      0.97      0.10      0.94      0.88       113

avg / total       1.00      0.97      0.91      0.99      0.94      0.89     71202
```

The score for individual class 0 and 1 are different even. Anyone has any idea why is this so?

Comment: The results look pretty similar to me and well within the variability one would expect simply by applying the two different implementation of the same methodology on a particular dataset. Aside the imbalance corrected geometric mean every other metric is 0.01 similar between implementations.